# String to date JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have some strings that represent dates:

`162021` change this to -> Jun, 1, 2021
`2182021` change this to -> Aug, 21, 2021

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Seems that I was wrong on this one ... I created keys using the date:

```
const dateObj = new Date();
let month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
const day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
const year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
const newDate = `${day}${month}${year}`;
```

Object will look like

```
{
newDate: something...
}
```

Now I want to use the dates and values to populate a line graph. I can change the format of the date ... but that would mean changes throughout the pp.

Comment: Is "2122021" the 21st of February 2021 or the 2nd of December? Seems like an ambiguous format.

Comment: Yeah ... I see what you mean. I can add 0. Like `02122021` and `02062021`

Comment: what is the date format on there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your question, you probably need something like this:

```
function stringToDate(str) {
   const months = 
   ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
   let currentMonth = str.slice(2,4);
   let currentDay = str.slice(0,2);
   let currentYear = str.slice(4,8);

   return `${months[Number(currentMonth) - 1]},${currentDay},${currentYear}`
}
stringToDate('21082021');// => Aug,21,2021
stringToDate('01062021');// => Jun,01,2021
```

What I changed, was that for days and months with a single digit I added a 0. This way it is easier to distinguish them.

Comment: yeah ... I think this might work. I still have to prefix all months and days below 10 with 0 from now on. thank you. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```js
new Date("2021/6/1")
```

if you can add "/".
it return "Tue Jun 01 2021 ..."

you can see it in devtools console, just type

```js
console.log(new Date("2021/6/1"))
```

and you can use String.prototype.slice() to get string you want by index

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you  :

```js
let date = new Date(if your date string is valid put in here)
let year = date.getFullYear()
let month = date.getMonth() + 1
let day = date.getDay()
let all = `${day}${month}${year}`
console.log(all)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
  ];
  var timestring = "02182021";

  var parts = timestring.match(/.{1,2}/g);
  var new_value = parts.join("-"); 
  new_value = new_value.slice(0, 8)+new_value.slice(9);  
  var new_date =  new Date(new_value);
  
  console.log(monthNames[new_date.getMonth()]+","+new_date.getDate()+","+new_date.getFullYear());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Function**

```
const formatMyStringDate=(stringDate)=>{
     const monthNames=["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
    let day=stringDate.substr(0,2);
        month=stringDate.substr(2,2);
        year =stringDate.substr(4,4);

        return `${monthNames[parseInt(month)-1]}, ${day}, ${year}`;
}
```

**try this**

```
let testDate=formatMyStringDate("02122021");
console.log(testDate)
```